# Laptop stick mouse problems after linux 4.4 update on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, dell, laptop

I have a Dell Precision 7510, running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I recently installed the latest kernel packages (4.4.0-57-generic), and when I did, it seems my laptop mouse is detected differently (used to be a PS/2 generic).

My TouchPad seems to be ok, but the Stick now acts with an extremely high sensitivity/acceleration to the point of being unusable, and I cannot lower it. I've raised it (using xfce mouse settings, under the Stick device), and when I did, the mouse literally goes from one corner of the screen to the other instantly.

I've tried the following commands, which resulted in zero change:

```
xset m 0 0
xset m 1/10 0
xset m 1/1000 0
```

I was able to use xinput to modify the TouchPad sensitivity by altering "Synaptics Finger", but it was finicky. It's well enough though, so I'm leaving it alone. The real problem is the Stick; which I cannot change through any property. See below:

```
xinput list                   
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (277):  422, 2394, 230, 1306
    Synaptics Finger (278): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (279):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (280):   141
    Synaptics Tap Durations (281):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (282):   0
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (283):  75
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (284):    141
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (285):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (286): 64, 64
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (287): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (288):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (289): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.062364, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (290):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (291):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (292):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (293): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (294):   1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (295): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (296):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (297): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (298):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (299): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (300):    10, 100
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (301): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (302):    15, 80
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (303): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (304):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (305):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (306):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (307):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (308): 47, 48
    Synaptics Area (309):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (310): 16, 16
    Device Product ID (268):    2, 8
    Device Node (269):  "/dev/input/event7"
</code>

<code>
└─[0] <> xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick"                  
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (268):    2, 8
    Device Node (269):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (312): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (314):  0
    Axis Labels (315):  "Rel X" (162), "Rel Y" (163)
    Button Labels (316):    "Button Left" (155), "Button Middle" (156), "Button Right" (157), "Button Wheel Up" (158), "Button Wheel Down" (159), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (160), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (161)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (317): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (318):    1
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (319):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (320): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (321): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (322):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (323):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (324):    1
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (325):   6, 7, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (326):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (327):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (328): 2
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (329):  0
```

I've messed with all of the Device Accel, properties, again, to no avail.

Thanks ahead for any ideas!!! This is driving me nuts, and I may have to stick on an old 3.x kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problems with my 7510 after installing a ubuntu based distro (16.04) with kernel 4.8.0-53, it wasn't a problem on my previous install which had an earlier kernel.

I've got the trackpoint to work much better by adjusting the following:

```
Device Accel Profile (264): 2
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   6.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
```

For anyone having this problem you can try out the different values by typing the following:

```
xinput set-float-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 6
```

... and then make that change permanent by:

```
echo "xinput set-prop 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 6" >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

I'm still having trouble with the trackpad, its very sensitive, it often will register a click while I'm typing. I'm also not happy with the scroll speed when using the trackpoint and middle button, its a bit too sensitive. But the trackpoint works well using the above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I changed the "Device Accel Profile" value to -1 and that seemed to help a little. Still way too sensitive though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I tried that one as well, and I didn't notice any difference. It might be very slight.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if the posters here have figured out anything else on this. No other bug reports I can find. I also have this issue. I use the trackpoint almost exclusively. The touchpad also now is much sensitive to false clicking and scrolling. I had to disable two finger scrolling to get it usable, and have no workaround for the trackpoint.

In the meantime I plan to just boot the old kernel before this update (4.4.0-47).

FYI I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1657553

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP.

Comment: Sorry to say, I have no answer yet.